# Некорректно работает bat-файл. C#

Tags: c#, bat, реестр

Есть bat-файл который изменяет реестр в разделе `LocalMachine`. Использую его, потому-что в `Registry.LocalMachine` нельзя удалять или создавать разделы.

Код bat-файла:

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RemoteComputer\NameSpace\{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}" /f
```

И есть код который запускает его. Но есть одна проблема, когда приложения выполняет bat-файл, то пишет: не удаётся найти указанный раздел или параметр в реестре. Если bat-файл запустить вручную, то всё работает. Что делать?

Код запуска bat-файла:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k cd " + Application.StartupPath + "/Bin & -searchprinters.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Programs";
        proc.Start();
```

Скриншот проблемы (запустил без прав, но работает):

[image: Выполнение bat-файлов]

Comment: `в Registry.LocalMachine нельзя удалять или создавать разделы` - с чего это вы взяли?

Comment: В документации написано

Comment: Ну, значит [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZFH4.png) магия...

Comment: Точно магия, даже чёрная - https://i.imgur.com/g4b26My.png

Comment: Ну так запустите ваш батник внучную от админа (пкм - запустить от администратора), получите такую же ошибку. Так может в реестре нету того, что вы ищите?

Comment: Батник вручную от админа работает.

Comment: Я вижу на скрине, как он работает, написав "отказано в доступе"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EKdItXJ.png - А сейчас?

Comment: А что вам самому кажется судя по надписи "Операция успешно выполнена"? Или вы её не читали, как и предыдущую про "отказано в доступе"?

Comment: Я смотрю что меняется в реестре после выполнения батника. Сейчас этот раздел отсутствует. https://i.imgur.com/qbded6l.png

Comment: На сколько я знаю, что C#, что CMD - это вызов одного и того-же, а именно, WinAPI методов и раз вам один позволяет, то должен позволять сделать это и другой. Так что вы что-то там мудрите явно, уточняйте значит вопрос, ибо на него нельзя дать ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас наверняка целевая архитектура сборки **Any CPU**.

Попробуйте через `Registry.LocalMachine`, но соберите приложение под **x64** архитектуру процессора. `.bat` файл тоже должен заработать.

Проблема кроется в `WOW64` виртуализации на 64-битной операционной системе для 32-битных приложений, подробности [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry).

Вылечить без изменения архитектуры сборки тоже [можно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view), но это уже сложнее.

Comment: приложение с аницпу итак будет 64х битным на 64х битной версии платформы. если все библиотеки которое оно использует тоже 64х битные. Registry.LocalMachine не даст вам ничего записать в реестр пока вы не запустите приложение от имени администратора. можно в самом приложении оперделить текущие привилегии и перезапустить в вербом runas и будет счастье.

Comment: @Yakov то есть чушь на Майкрософте пишут, так чтоли? Я проверил этот момент перед тем как постить ответ. **Any CPU** не работает реестр как надо автору, **x64** - работает. Запускать от имени администратора умею, как и автор вопроса, не переживайте.

Comment: wow64 редирект можно отключить, смд32х битный. проблему можно решить также указав в reg какой куст реестра надо редактировать 64 или 32. можно было просто указать /reg:64 в параметрах

Comment: @Yakov а вот это верное утверждение, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Дабы не быть голословным пример с реального проекта. приложение 32х битное билд х86, т.к. библиотеки сдк 32х битные. но нужно при старте настраивать в реестре поведение смарткарт при поднесении к считывателю. но драйвера 64х битные ( у считывателя ) поэтому была задача в обоих ветвях реестра править данные.

```
public static Process RunAsAdmin(string aFileName, string anArguments,ProcessWindowStyle style=ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,String dir=null)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    if(dir!=null)
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;
    processInfo.FileName = aFileName;
    processInfo.Arguments = anArguments;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processInfo.WindowStyle = style;
    processInfo.Verb = "runas"; // здесь вся соль
    return System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);
}
void public static createKeys()
{       
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /reg:32 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /reg:64 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ATR /t REG_BINARY /d 0003 /reg:32 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ATRMASK /t REG_BINARY /d ffff /reg:32 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ATR /t REG_BINARY /d 0003 /reg:64 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ATRMASK /t REG_BINARY /d ffff /reg:64 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ""Crypto Provider"" /t REG_SZ /d TEST /reg:32 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
    RunAsAdmin("reg", @"ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\Unknown /v ""Crypto Provider"" /t REG_SZ /d TEST /reg:64 /f", System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden);
}
```